# Unwanted space between username and password edittext at Login Page in xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms, devexpress

That's my login page. "Kullanıcı kodu" means user code, "Şifre" means password. I don't want these space between user code and password edittext. I used devexpress ComboboxEdit and TextEdit. I tried to change margin, padding, layout's padding, grid's height, textedit height request... but there is no change. Those space still remain there!

[image]

**XAML**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout  
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  Margin="15" Padding="5">
        <Image Source="@drawable/ida_logo" />
        <Label x:Name="denemeText"
               Text="Çözüm Ortağınız" 
               FontSize="Title" 
               TextColor="Black" 
               FontFamily = "LobsterTwoItalic"   
               xct:ShadowEffect.Color="SlateGray"   
               xct:ShadowEffect.Opacity="0.8"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition  Height="80"/>
                
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit  
                            
                            x:Name="databasePicker"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            LabelText="Veritabanı"
                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                            LabelColor="Black"  
                            TextFontSize="18"
                            LabelFontSize="18"
                            DropDownItemFontSize="18"
                            BottomTextFontSize="18"
                            AffixFontSize="18"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            TextFontFamily="Roboto"
                            AffixFontFamily="Roboto"
                            BottomTextFontFamily="Roboto"
                            DropDownItemFontFamily="Roboto"
                            DropDownItemTextColor="Black"
                            DropDownSelectedItemTextColor="Black"                                 
                            TextHorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            HeightRequest="60"
                            TextColor="Black"  />



            
            <dxe:TextEdit
                x:Name="loginCustomEntryKullanici"
                 
                
                 LabelText="Kullanıcı Kodu"
                 TextFontSize="18"
                 LabelFontSize="18"
                 BottomTextFontSize="18"
                 AffixFontSize="18"
                 LabelColor="Black"
                 BackgroundColor="White"
                 BorderColor="Black"
                 ReserveBottomTextLine="True"
                 AutofillContentType="None"
                 IsLabelFloating="True"
                 AffixFontFamily="Roboto"
                 BottomTextFontFamily="Roboto"
                 TextFontFamily="Roboto"
                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                 HeightRequest="90"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            
            />
            <dxe:PasswordEdit
               x:Name="loginCustomEntryPass"
                
                 LabelText="Şifre"
                 TextFontSize="18"
                 LabelFontSize="18"
                 BottomTextFontSize="18"
                 LabelColor="Black"
                 BackgroundColor="White"
                 BorderColor="Black"
                 ReserveBottomTextLine="True"
                 IsLabelFloating="True"
                 BottomTextFontFamily="Roboto"
                 TextFontFamily="Roboto"
                 Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HeightRequest="80"
            
            />
                 

        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="giris_Button" 
                Text="Giriş Yap" 
                TextColor="Black"
                FontSize="Medium"
                Clicked="giris_Button_Clicked1" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                BorderColor="Black"  
                BorderWidth="1"
                CornerRadius="8"
                xct:TouchEffect.AnimationDuration="250"
                xct:TouchEffect.AnimationEasing="{x:Static Easing.CubicInOut}"
                xct:TouchEffect.PressedScale="1.25"
                xct:TouchEffect.PressedBackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                xct:TouchEffect.NormalBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                />
        
        


    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Can you please try to add Margin like Margin="0,0,0,0" under <dxe:PasswordEdit, pls do not forget to change 0,0,0,0 to desired adjustments

Comment: Thank you for answer but nothing changed.

Comment: I set top and bottom margin -10 `Margin="0,-10,0,-10"`  and move all buttons and text edit elements into my grid. Then they come to a good place.

Comment: `<StackLayout>` has a default spacing of 6, removing that would probably fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different row heights defined and if the heights of the controls inside the rows don't match with the row heights, you'll see gaps.

I'm almost certain that the differences between the row heights and the actual heights of the controls are causing this.

Try changing the RowDefinitions from this:

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    <RowDefinition Height="80" />
    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

to this:

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

***Note:** Usually, it's not recommended to have several RowDefinitions with the `Auto` setting, but I believe that's the root of the issue here, so you might want to give that a try.*

You may also need to change or remove the `HeightRequest` settings from the `ComboBoxEdit`, `TextEdit` and `PasswordEdit` controls.

Alternatively, you can also give each row the same height:

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and then also make sure to give your controls the same `HeightRequest="60"`:

```xml
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit
    HeightRequest="60" />

<dxe:TextEdit
    HeightRequest="60" />

<dxe:PasswordEdit
    HeightRequest="60" />
```

Comment: I set grid height is 80, remove height request from textedit elements and set top and bottom margin -10. It comes a good place. Looks the same right now.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set it with Margin, you may experience problems with different resolutions. Automatic row alignment will be more accurate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).